# App Tab Bar Multiple View Crash

Tags: iphone

I have a tab bar app with multiple views on each tab. A button is pressed in a tab to take you to a different xib view. A button there is pressed to take you back to the first tab in the tab bar. The problem is when i press the button to go back, I don't want to go to the first view for the FirstViewController, I want to go the the mainwindow where the tab bar controller and stuff is. The button takes you to the firstview without the tab bar. If I change the code to initWithNibName@"MainWindow" it crashes when i press the button. What should I do?

Here is the code in question:

```
-(IBAction)back{ 
    FirstViewController *back = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainWindow" bundle:nil]; 
    [self presentModalViewController:back animated:YES]; 
} //this is for going back 

-(IBAction)forward{ 
    test2 *forward = [[test2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"test2" bundle:nil]; 
    [self presentModalViewController:forward animated:NO]; 
} //this is for going to the view. by the way there are no errors or warnings, just "Debugging Terminated" when it crashes.
```

Comment: Show us the relevant code. How are we supposed to help you without it?

Comment: What's the code look like? Define "crashes". Is there console output? Recommended reading: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: -(IBAction)back{
 FirstViewController *back = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainWindow" bundle:nil];
 [self presentModalViewController:back animated:YES];
} //this is for going back                                                                       -(IBAction)forward{
 test2 *forward = [[test2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"test2" bundle:nil];
 [self presentModalViewController:forward animated:NO];
} //this is for going to the view. by the way there are no errors or warnings, just "Debugging Terminated" when it crashes.

Comment: You should edit your question and add the code there (in a readable manner).

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `presentModalViewController` to go back or forward.  Modal view controllers should be though of as temporary utility views.

If you are in a navigationController, then you have to use `pushViewController:animated:` to "drill down" and `popViewController:animated:` to go back.